# Parâmetro aceitável pré-definido na função PHP

Tags: php, funções

No exemplo:

```
public function getEstoqueDeposito($busca, $deposito = FALSE) {
    ...
}
```

Sei que poderia fazer:

```
public function getEstoqueDeposito($busca, $deposito = FALSE) {
    if($busca == 'TOTAL'){
        ...
        return "whatever";
    } else if($busca == 'GRUPO'){
        ...
        return "whatever";
    } 
    return "Parâmetro inválido";
}
```

Enfim, gostaria de pré-definir os valores (TOTAL ou GRUPO) no parâmetro $busca, no PHP, tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem a necessidade de fazer um teste dentro da função?

Comment: Acho que não entendi, você ja fez isso em $deposito, só fazer o mesmo em busca $busca = 'TOTAL'

Comment: Olá Anderson, não é pré-definir se não for passado o parâmetro, na verdade preciso que a função só aceite TOTAL ou GRUPO no parâmetro $busca.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php